# Highlighting partial duplicate values

Tags: excel

I have a list of IP addresses in an excel file and I need to find duplicates based on IP ranges, not the entire values. For example, if I have IP addresses 109.184.137.22 and 109.184.138.170, can I format to show that these are duplicates based on the first 7 digits?

Comment: Add a column using (e.g.) `=LEFT(A2,7)` - hilight dups in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine IP's in A1:A10,

Select A1:A10, conditional formatting, new rule, use a formula to determine which cells to format and then write the formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10;LEFT(A1;7)&"*")>1
```

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would split it and then just rejoin the first two octets since an IP address is sometimes notated as 42.192.63.10 or some such. I would use this to loop through a column and highlight anything with matching IPs... or I guess you could remove the loop to just check on a cell by cell basis.

```
Sub IPCheck()
Dim arrSplit As Variant
Dim strSearchFor As String
Dim iVal As Integer
Dim strJoinMe() As String
ReDim strJoinMe(0 To 1)

Do Until ActiveCell = ""
arrSplit = Split(ActiveCell.Value2, ".")
strJoinMe(0) = arrSplit(0)
strJoinMe(1) = arrSplit(1)
strSearchFor = Join(strJoinMe, ".")
strSearchFor = strSearchFor & "*"

iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A10"), strSearchFor)

If iVal > 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop
```